# When to delete expired rows from a database?

Tags: database, token, rdbms, theory

For my current web project, I need to store short-lived access tokens in a PostgreSQL table. I have two options in mind for implementing token expiration:

1. When authenticating a user, make sure the token is not expired, e.g. by doing `SELECT * FROM access_token WHERE key = '...' AND CURTIME() < expires_at;`. Delete expired tokens in large chunks independently from the web application with `cron` or something similar.

   **Pros:** Faster authentications, overall fewer queries to the database.

   **Cons:** Need for a scheduler or an external tool, therefore a more complex project.
2. Before every authentication, run `DELETE FROM access_token WHERE CURTIME() >= expires_at;`. Then `SELECT` the token, provided that it still exists.

   **Pros:** Simpler and easier to implement, less expired tokens are accumulated.

   **Cons:** More queries, potentially much longer authentications for individual users (e.g. first user after a period of downtime).

Are there other solutions? Which one is considered a best practice?

Answer (score 0):

When you talk of best practice it is important to first consider the trade-offs which you have already stated, however the first option is appropriate

**However, this is how i approach the situation**

When authenticating the user check if the token is expired or not, then you can have a trigger that automatically deletes expired tokens. This is how i would approach the situations, and this is how i have seen it done. It might seem complex but at the end you would reap the rewards.

Again, others might have a different opinion, this is just my 2 cents.